# Ampersand Character and Issues with the Rating field type

Tags: content-rating, list

I encountered what appeared to be a SP2010 bug, but I can't find any other information from others who have experienced it.

We had a site with a SharePoint list with a Title field and a Rating field (and many other fields).  If the Title contained an ampersand, then the Rating would not save.  Neither would the user see their own rating as saved if they re-opened, nor would it be added to the calculated average rating.

When we changed the titles to remove the ampersand, the rating feature began to work again.

Is this a known bug?

Comment: We've also just recently seen the same issue.

Comment: Exactly the same issue here! Any solutions?
Marc

Answer (score 1):

Is the Title field, the so-called name of each list item?

Invalid characters in a file name include : " # % & * : < > ? \ / { | } ~

For more character restrictions see this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joelo/archive/2007/06/27/file-name-length-size-and-invalid-character-restrictions-and-recommendations.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should escape the ampersand to be:

```
&amp;
```

instead of just a &

Comment: You can't ask the user to html-encode their input. The best you can do (without a bugfix from MS), is t forbid the use of a & in the column